# Kurtosis of sum of gaussian variables

Tags: statistics

The sum of two gaussian random variables is also a gaussian, right. The Kurtosis of the sum should also be 3 in that case. But if I use the expression for the kurtosis of the sum of two random variables, one will get an answer that is different than 3 depending on the variance of the individual random variables. How is this explained then?

Comment: So what is this expression for the kurtosis of the sum of two random variables that you are using?

Comment: I looked in the wiki page of Kurtosis as well as the below thread 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289706/kurtosis-of-sum-of-independent-random-variables

Comment: Please see Lythia's comment in the question you linked.  The formula applies to excess kurtosis, which is zero for each of the Gaussian and so the formula will give you zero for the excess kurtosis of the sum too.  i.e., the kurtosis of the sum is 3

Comment: Okay. I get that. But if I follow the derivation by wintermute in the same thread for kurtosis and not the excess kurtosis, I would get different from 3. Does this mean this derivation is wrong?